# Blackjack game in Python 2.7

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, playing-cards

Please review my game. I am learning Python now, so any suggestions are welcome. I am running this on a Linux machine, in Komodo and terminal.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#encoding=utf8  
import random

# init global variables used for game
player = []
dealer = []

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self,rank=[], suit=[], whole_deck=[], scrambled_deck=[]):
        self.rank = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','J','Q','K','A']
        self.suit = ['♠','♣','♥','♦︎︎']
        self.whole_deck = whole_deck
        self.scrambled_deck = scrambled_deck
        #construct deck from existing attributes
        def makedeck(self):
            self.whole_deck = []            
            i=0
            while i < 4:
                for r in self.rank:
                    self.whole_deck.append(r+self.suit[i])  
                i += 1
            return self.whole_deck
        self.whole_deck = makedeck(self)

    def draw_a_card(self):
        d=self.whole_deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(self.whole_deck))))
        return d

class Game(Deck):
    def __init__(self,credit=100, bet=10):
        Deck.__init__(self)
        self.credit = credit
        self.bet = bet
    def getcredit(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.credit = int(raw_input("How many chips would you like to buy? "))
            except:
                print "You need to specify number"
                continue
            else:
                print str(self.credit) + ' Chips Purchased'
                print "Have fun!"
                break
        return self.credit
    def makebet(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.bet = int(raw_input("How much do you want to bet? "))
            except:
                print "You need to specify number"
                continue
            if self.bet > self.credit:
                print 'You can\'t bet more than you have credit'
                continue
            else:
                print 'You are betting ' + str(self.bet) 
                break
    def deal(self, p_turn=0, d_turn=0):
        global dealer
        global player
        i = 0
        j = 0
        while i < p_turn:
            player.append(g.draw_a_card())
            i += 1
        while j < d_turn:
            dealer.append(g.draw_a_card())
            j += 1

def clear_screen():
    print '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'

####################Construct Cards####################
def makecard(dealer, player, hidden=0):
    card =   ['╔═══════╗\t','║ {}     ║\t','║       ║\t','║   {}   ║\t','║       ║\t','║     {} ║\t','╚═══════╝\t']
    h_card = ['╔═══════╗\t','║▓▓▓▓▓▓▓║\t' ,'║▒▒▒▒▒▒▒║\t','║▓▓▓▓▓▓▓║\t' ,'║▒▒▒▒▒▒▒║\t','║▓▓▓▓▓▓▓║\t' ,'╚═══════╝\t']

    global player_cards
    player_cards = ['' for i in player]
    c=0
    p=0
    while p < len(player):
        for c in range(0, len(card)):
            alter = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
            current_card=[player[p][:1], player[p][1:]]
            player_cards[p] += str(card[c]).format(current_card[alter[c]])
        player_cards[p] = player_cards[p].split("\t")
        p += 1

    global dealer_cards
    dealer_cards = ['' for i in dealer]
    c=0
    p=0 

    while p < len(dealer):
        for c in range(0, len(card)):
            alter = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
            current_card=[dealer[p][:1], dealer[p][1:]]
            dealer_cards[p] += str(card[c]).format(current_card[alter[c]])
        dealer_cards[p] = dealer_cards[p].split("\t")
        p += 1

    if  hidden == 1:
        dealer_cards[1]=''.join(h_card)
        dealer_cards[1] = dealer_cards[1].split("\t")

def printcards(dealer_cards, player_cards):
    for i in range(len(dealer_cards[0])):
        for j in range(len(dealer_cards)):
            print '{}'.format(dealer_cards[j][i]),
        print

    for i in range(len(player_cards[0])):
        for j in range(len(player_cards)):
            print '{}'.format(player_cards[j][i]),
        print
####################Construct Cards END####################

def makerank(who):
    i=0
    player_rank = []
    while i < len(who):
        player_rank.append(who[i][0])

        for ii in player_rank:
            player_rank = [10 if ii=='K' or ii=='Q' or ii=='J' else ii for ii in player_rank]

        for ii in player_rank:        
            if ii == 'A':
                tmp_suit = player_rank.pop()
    #            tmp_suit = player_rank.pop(player_rank.index(ii))            
                if sum([ int(x) for x in player_rank]) <= 10:
                    tmp_suit = 11
                    player_rank.append(tmp_suit)
                elif sum([ int(x) for x in player_rank]) > 10:
                    tmp_suit = 1
                    player_rank.append(tmp_suit)
        i += 1         

    player_rank = [ int(x) for x in player_rank ]
    return sum(player_rank)

def newdeck(mindecksize):
    d = Deck()
    if len(g.whole_deck) < mindecksize: 
        g.whole_deck = d.whole_deck

def cards(z):
    if z == 0:
        makecard(dealer, player, 0)
        printcards(dealer_cards, player_cards)
    elif z == 1:
        makecard(dealer, player, 1)
        printcards(dealer_cards, player_cards)

def winlose(who):
    if who == 'p':
        g.credit = g.credit + g.bet
        print 'You win!'
        print 'Your credit is: ' + str(g.credit)
    elif who == 'd':
        g.credit = g.credit - g.bet
        print 'Dealer wins!'
        print 'Your credit is: ' + str(g.credit)       
    elif who == 'dr':
        print 'Push'
        print 'Your credit is: ' + str(g.credit)               

def dealerplay():
    while makerank(dealer) < 17:
        g.deal(0,1)

#Debug functions, can be removed at any time

def debug_printset():
    i=0
    while i < len(player):
        print player[i]
        i += 1

# Functions end here
g = Game()

def play():
    d = Deck()
    global g
    global player
    global dealer
    i = 0
    clear_screen()
    g.getcredit()
    while True: #Whole game loop
        player = []
        dealer = []      
        g.deal(2,2)
        i += 1
        clear_screen()
        g.makebet()
        cards(1)
        newdeck(5)
        #########################Is it blackjack?#########################
        if makerank(player) == 21: 
            if i == 1 and makerank(dealer) != 21:
                print 'Blackjack!'
                winlose('p')
                break
            elif i == 1 and makerank(dealer) == 21:
                winlose('dr')
                break
        #########################Is it blackjack? END#########################        
        while True: #hand loop              
            player_input = str(raw_input("Press 'h' to hit, or 's' to stand \n"))
            if player_input == 'h':
                newdeck(1)
                g.deal(1)
                if makerank(player) > 21:
                    clear_screen()
                    cards(0)
                    print 'Busted!'
                    winlose('d')
                    break
                elif makerank(player) < 21:
                    clear_screen()
                    cards(1)
                    continue
                elif makerank(player) == 21:
                    clear_screen()
                    cards(0)
                    dealerplay()
                    if makerank(dealer) == 21:
                        winlose('dr')
                        break
                    elif makerank(dealer) < 21:
                        winlose('p')
                        break

            elif player_input == 's':
                dealerplay()
                clear_screen()
                cards(0)
                if  makerank(dealer) > 21:
                    winlose('p')
                    break
                elif makerank(dealer) > makerank(player):
                    winlose('d')
                    break
                elif makerank(dealer) < makerank(player):
                    winlose('p')
                    break
                elif makerank(dealer) == makerank(player):
                    winlose('dr')
                    break
###############Gameover?####################
        if g.credit == 0:
            print "Game Over"
            exit()  
###############Play again?##################            
        while True: 
            print len(g.whole_deck)
            print 'press \'d\' to deal again, or \'c\' to close'
            deal = str(raw_input())
            if deal == 'd':
                i -= 1
                break
            elif deal == 'c':
                print 'Game ended. Your remaining credit is: ' + str(g.credit)
                exit()
            else:
                print "Incorrect input, please input 'd' to Deal again, 'c' to close the game"
                continue
###############Play again? END##################            

play()
```

Comment: This is the coolest freaking thing I've ever seen in my life.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I think you did a good job overall.  That is, getting the game logic to run without serious issue.  There were a couple of errors that caused the game to not run correctly.  One was if the `player` gets a blackjack the game exits without prompting the user for further action:

**LOGIC**

```
while True: #Whole game loop
    player = []
    dealer = []      
    .....
    if makerank(player) == 21: 
        if i == 1 and makerank(dealer) != 21:
            print 'Blackjack!'
            winlose('p')
            break
        elif i == 1 and makerank(dealer) == 21:
            winlose('dr')
            break       
    while True: #hand loop              
    ..........
```

I shortened the code up here but you can see since you do your check outside of "hand-loop" and call `break` you will exit the program.  This goes for if there is a push on blackjack too.

Exhausting the `deck`, where you only reset the deck if the player hits.  This is because of how you are drawing cards by calling `.pop`.

```
.....
if player_input == 'h':
    newdeck(1)

.....
def draw_a_card(self):
    d=self.whole_deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(self.whole_deck))))
    return d
```

If you keep standing on every turn you will eventually get an `IndexError`.  You could just call `random.choice` on the deck and not have to worry about it while using some other condition to reset the `deck`:

```
def draw_a_card(self):
    return random.choice(self.whole_deck)
```

**STYLE**

There are some style issues here too.  These usually come down to personal preferences but if you are having others read your code its best to stay close to [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which is a general consesus for helpful style choices.

**OOP**

You also make use of `global` variables quite a bit.  Usually using `global`s are considered bad practice.  What you could do is think about where each one of these functions and variables would logically make sense to be grouped together.  Then create a class to encapsulate the variables and functions, adhering to good OOP principles.  You do this to a certain degree but you could further it by adding in the `global`s too:

```
class Game(Deck):
    def __init__(self,credit=100, bet=10):
        Deck.__init__(self)
        self.credit = credit
        self.bet = bet
        # make an attribute for hands
        self.player = []
        self.dealer = []
```

**CODE DUPLICATION**

You also have several spots of code duplication.  Keeping with DRY (don't repeat yourself) you could use a loop or recursion to cut down on some of this:

```
def printcards(dealer_cards, player_cards):
    for i in range(len(dealer_cards[0])):
        for j in range(len(dealer_cards)):
            print '{}'.format(dealer_cards[j][i]),
        print

    for i in range(len(player_cards[0])):
        for j in range(len(player_cards)):
            print '{}'.format(player_cards[j][i]),
        print
```

Where you could pass in a `list` or any other kind of `iterable` and loop for them:

```
def printcards(hands): # where hands have both player and dealer cards
    for hand in hands:
        for i in range(len(hand[0]):
        .....
```

There are places where you are using counters too where iterating over the list itself or a range would be fine:

```
p=0
...
while p < len(dealer):
    for c in range(0, len(card)):
        alter = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
        current_card=[dealer[p][:1], dealer[p][1:]]
        dealer_cards[p] += str(card[c]).format(current_card[alter[c]])
    dealer_cards[p] = dealer_cards[p].split("\t")
    p += 1
```

would be:

```
for p in range(len(dealer)):
    for c in range(0, len(card)):
        alter = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
        current_card=[dealer[p][:1], dealer[p][1:]]
        dealer_cards[p] += str(card[c]).format(current_card[alter[c]])
    dealer_cards[p] = dealer_cards[p].split("\t")
```

**STANDARD LIBRARY**

One of the great things about Python is that there are a rich collection of libraries/modules already made by really intelligent people.  Use this to your advantage and get to know different modules and what they offer:

```
self.whole_deck = []            
i=0
while i < 4:
    for r in self.rank:
        self.whole_deck.append(r+self.suit[i])  
    i += 1
```

becomes:

```
from itertools import product
.....
return [''.join(c) for c in product(self.rank, self.suit)]
```

Where you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to create a cartesian product

I re-wrote your program by creating a different game-loop and making a couple of different classes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#encoding=utf8  

import random


card =   ['╔═══════╗\t',
          '║ {}     ║\t',
          '║       ║\t',
          '║   {}   ║\t',
          '║       ║\t',
          '║     {} ║\t',
          '╚═══════╝\t'
         ]

h_card = ['╔═══════╗\t',
          '║▓▓▓▓▓▓▓║\t',
          '║▒▒▒▒▒▒▒║\t',
          '║▓▓▓▓▓▓▓║\t',
          '║▒▒▒▒▒▒▒║\t',
          '║▓▓▓▓▓▓▓║\t',
          '╚═══════╝\t'
         ]

def make_rank(hand):
    hand_rank = 0
    hand_str = ''.join(card[0] for card in hand)
    for card in hand_str:
        if card.isdigit():
            hand_rank += int(card)
        else:
            hand_rank += 10 if card in 'KQJ' else 11
    if hand_rank > 21 and 'A' in hand_str:
        hand_rank -= 10
    return hand_rank

def make_cards(hand, hidden=False):
    cards = [''.join(card).format(*c).split('\t') for c in hand]
    if hidden:
        cards[1] = ''.join(h_card).split('\t')
    return cards

def print_cards(hands, hidden=False):
    for pos, hand in enumerate(hands):
        cards = make_cards(hand, (not pos) & hidden)
        for card in zip(*cards):
            print(''.join(card))
        print

def clear_screen(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print '\n' * 66
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

@clear_screen
def get_credit():
    while True:
        try:
            credit = int(raw_input("How many chips would you like to buy? "))
        except:
            print "You need to specify number"
            continue
        print '{} Chips Purchased'.format(credit)
        print "Have fun!"
        break
    return credit

@clear_screen
def make_bet(player):
    while True:
        try:
            bet = int(raw_input("How much do you want to bet? "))
        except:
            print "You need to specify number"
            continue
        if bet > player.credit:
            print 'You can\'t bet more than you have credit'
            continue
        print 'You are betting {}'.format(bet) 
        break
    player.credit -= bet
    return bet

def deal_again(option=''):
    if option == 'c':
        return False
    elif option == 'd':
        return True
    if option:
        print 'Incorrect input, please input "d" to Deal again, "c" to close the game'
    print 'press \'d\' to deal again, or \'c\' to close'
    option = raw_input()
    return deal_again(option)

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self,rank=[], suit=[], whole_deck=[], scrambled_deck=[]):
        self.rank = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','J','Q','K','A']
        self.suit = ['♠','♣','♥','♦︎︎']
        self.whole_deck = whole_deck
        self.scrambled_deck = scrambled_deck
        def makedeck(self):
            return [(r, s, r) for r in self.rank for s in self.suit]
        self.whole_deck = makedeck(self)

    def draw_a_card(self):
        return random.choice(self.whole_deck)


class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, dealer):
        self.hand = []
        self.credit = 0
        self.dealer = dealer


class Dealer(object):

    def __init__(self, bet=10):
        self.deck = Deck()
        self.bet = bet
        self.hand = []
        self.table_hands = [self.hand]

    def add_player(self, player):
        self.table_hands.append(player)

    @property
    def clear_cards(self):
        self.table_hands = [[] for hand in self.table_hands]

    def deal_hand(self):
        self.clear_cards
        self.deal(self.table_hands, 2)

    def deal(self, hands, turn):
        for _ in range(turn):
            for hand in hands:
                hand.append(self.deck.draw_a_card())

    def winlose(self, who):
        payout = 0
        if who == 'p':
            print 'You win!'
            payout = self.bet * 2
        elif who == 'd':
            print 'Dealer wins!'
        else:
            print 'Push'
            payout = self.bet
        return payout

    @clear_screen
    def dealer_play(self, rank):
        dealer_hand = self.table_hands[0]
        if rank > 16:
            return rank
        self.deal([dealer_hand], 1)
        rank = make_rank(dealer_hand)
        print_cards(self.table_hands)
        return self.dealer_play(rank)

    @clear_screen
    def player_play(self, rank, option=''):
        player_hand = self.table_hands[1]
        if option == 'h':
            self.deal([player_hand], 1)
            rank = make_rank(player_hand)
        print_cards(self.table_hands, True)
        if rank >= 21 or option == 's':
            return rank
        player_input = raw_input('Press "h" to hit, or "s" to stand \n')
        return self.player_play(rank, player_input)


def play_hand(dealer, player):
    dealer.deal_hand()
    print_cards(dealer.table_hands, True)
    d_rank, p_rank = map(make_rank, dealer.table_hands)
    msg = ''
    if p_rank == 21 or d_rank == 21:
        msg = 'BlackJack!'
        winner = 'p' if p_rank == 21 and d_rank != 21 else \
                 'd' if p_rank != 21 else 'dr'
    else:
        p_rank = dealer.player_play(p_rank)
        if p_rank > 21:
            msg = 'Bust'
            winner = 'd'
        else:
            d_rank = dealer.dealer_play(d_rank)
            if d_rank > 21 or p_rank <= 21 and d_rank < p_rank:
                winner = 'p'
            elif p_rank < 21 and d_rank > p_rank:
                winner = 'd'
            else:
                winner = 'dr'
    clear_screen(lambda:None)()
    if msg:
        print msg
    player.credit += dealer.winlose(winner)
    print_cards(dealer.table_hands)
    print 'Your credit is: {}'.format(player.credit)

def take_seat_at_table():
    dealer = Dealer()
    player = Player(dealer)
    PLAYING = True
    player.credit = get_credit()
    dealer.add_player(player.hand)
    while PLAYING:
        dealer.bet = make_bet(player)
        play_hand(dealer, player)
        if player.credit == 0:
            print 'Game Over'
            PLAYING = False
        else:
            PLAYING = deal_again()
    print 'Game ended. Your remaining credit is: {}'.format(player.credit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    take_seat_at_table()
```

Comment: This is the best review of my work ever, school university or anything else. It's amazing that you took so much time. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [a similar question](/a/148176/9357), the deck should be constructed using a list comprehension. There is no rank "1", but there should be a "10".